# What is the male counterpart called for a damsel?

Tags: word-request

I know the word 'damsel'. It means a young, unmarried woman. What is the word for a young unmarried man?

Internet gives me results like "lad" and "dude", but I am not sure.

Comment: *damoiseau* is the word but it's not English!

Comment: [What is the male equivalent of “damsel”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50048/what-is-the-male-equivalent-of-damsel)

Comment: By the way, some argue that *'dude'* is also good alternate! And, it also sounds pretty *okay*. Just a thought - can 'dude' be a married man? ^-^

Comment: *Dude and Damsel* could very well be the name of a hair salon here in the US. Or a farcical rom-com: *The Dude and the Damsel*, opening December 1st at a theater near you.  But the words are worlds apart.

Answer (score 3):

**damsel** is a rather old-fashioned term (12th C but fell from use, revived in the 16th C by the romantic poets) meaning a [young lady of noble birth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=damsel), so I think that you need a similarly old-fashioned term.

**bachelor** used to fit the bill- [youthful knight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bachelor), though now it seems quite prosaic and it no longer carries any suggestion of social status.

**squire** - [young man who attends a knight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=squire). Squire can also be used as a verb for **to attend (a lady) as a gallant**

**gallant** - [A dashing and fashionable gentleman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gallant)

Comment: _Gallant_ is precisely right. _Bachelor_ is not, though. In modern parlance it connotes an unmarried man of any station, and that meaning eclipses its earlier connotations. _Damoiseau_ is correct according to the Norman dictionary, but _gallant_ is much closer to the male equivalent of the modern appreciation of _damsel._